# Travis CI : Switch to python 3 temporarily

Tags: python, travis-ci

Okay, so I am trying to generate and deploy the documentation of a Python 2.7 based package. The documentation is generated using sphinx, python 2.7.

However, to actually deploy the documentation, I need to use a tool called doctr. This automatically deploys the generated html to github pages. However it requires me to work on Python 3.5 or newer.

So the question is : **When the entire travis build is running on python 2.7, how do I temporarily shift to python 3.5 and deploy the documentation?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyenv` to install 3.5 if not already present, and change to it, do your thing, and change back.

Basically this;

```
pyenv install 3.5.0
pyenv global 3.5.0
<do the deploy>
pyenv global <previous version>
```

Comment: How can the pyenv version be printed? When running `pyenv version` I end up getting a blurb about "set by host" rather than the version. (sorry I don't remember it at the moment)

Comment: @ChrisSharp Try `pyenv versions` cmd instead.